# Using ADC for the first time, not sure how to choose a microcontroller for this

Tags: microcontroller, ac, adc

I have a 300 kHz signal with 5Vp-p; therefore, I would like to use [LTC2315](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/231512fa.pdf) which is 12-bit and has a sampling rate of 5 MHz. Reading the datasheet, it mentions that it uses SPI. My question is  how do I decide on a which microcontroller to use with LTC2315.

I have always used Arduino, and this is my first time learning in-depth about ADC and its connection.

I want to use the ADC to find the max and min value of the input signal.
I hope to learn from your response.

Comment: Other than one that has an SPI interface it's hard to answer.  What else do you need to do with the micro and the samples?  Are you planning to perform DSP on the samples? Do you need real-time processing? You'll have to add a lot more information in order to get a useful answer.  It's also a borderline shopping question, which is off-topic for this site.

Comment: if you have an Arduino, then use it ... it will give you a better sense of what you need

Comment: The problem with Arduino is the Arduino mindset. "I have a hammer, I used it for nails". Next project: screw a screw - use the hammer. Next project: saw a plank - use the hammer, buy an external saw interface. And so on. But in real-world projects, the MCU is picked to suit the requirements (and budget) of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you don't use external ADC unless you have very specialized requirements. In case you need very high resolution, galvanic isolation or a whole lot of channels etc etc. Otherwise, the normal application is to use the internal ADC in the microcontroller. There's a wide range of these available too - 12 bit and 5MHz doesn't sound impossible to find.

Next question is if you really need 5MHz - are you going to store and process every single sample at that rate? That's quite CPU-intensive no matter if you use internal or external. In most applications it is sufficient to have a "conversion complete" feature of the ADC where your program goes to grab the latest sample when it has time for it, ideally periodically (once every 1ms, 10ms or whatever makes sense). For higher sampling rates you should strongly consider a MCU with DMA so that you don't have to process ADC interrupts (or SPI interrupts in case of external ADC).

So the answer to your question is very likely to forget about this ADC you've found and forget about Arudino. Write a specification where it says what accuracy you need and how often you truly need to sample, then pick MCU accordingly. In most cases you can likely use an on-chip ADC, though you might need to consider how pure an ADC Vref you need, or if using the regular supply voltage on board is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You need a microcontroller that is fast enough to read what you need on a serial interface.

If you have a 300KHz signal, you need to sample it at 600Ksps to meet the Nyquist criterion.  That is 12-bits per sample which I will round up to 16 to account for some overhead.  That's about 1 bit every 100nS which is about a 10MHz SPI bus.  That's pretty fast for most Arduino's as their system frequency is 16MHz.

Side Note 1: you need to read that LTC2315 datasheet more carefully.  On the internal reference you can only go to 4.096V (and only 4.3V even if you supply an outside reference).  If you need 5V, you need an ADC that can do that full range/full scale.

Side Note 2: Nyquist sampling would allow you to reconstruct the waveform digitally to extract the max/min with digital filtering.  In reality, you're unlikely to do that on cheaper microcontrollers, so you will need to wind your sampling rate up until an excursion between samples has a bounded limit that you find acceptable.

Good luck.